# Initiatives to systematically archive researchers' notes

Tags: ho.history-overview, research

> Are there ongoing initiatives to systematically archive all notes of mathematicians?  If not, what body (the IMU? the AMS? The Clay fundation?...) should I contact to make that case?

Of course in the case of exceptional mathematicians, e.g. Grothendieck and Quillen in recent years, there has been heavy editorial work to have some of their notes published online.

But what I'm thinking of is rather different: no editorial activity, just some basic bibliographic metadata, and no big author restriction. Rather, it would be a worldwide archive of any set of notes, handwritten or texed, that any research mathematicians (or their heirs) decide to transmit, either upon hitting retirement or during the course of their career. It would provide very valuable historical material, and also artistically pleasant handwritten pages in many hands and languages, sometimes with hand-drawn illustrations.

Comment: Related: [Big list of repositories of mathematical preprints and postprints](https://mathoverflow.net/q/186708/15780) *AND* [Unpublished Lecture Notes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132393/15780). Marginally related: [Wayback Machine for mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373681/15780) *AND* [Archiving of MathOverflow threads](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2447/15780).